# Is the use of "Elysial" acceptable / correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Based on the following definition:

> elysian
>
> adj
>
> 1. (Classical Myth & Legend) of or relating to Elysium
> 2. delightful; glorious; blissful
>
> Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged
>   © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003

Is it acceptable to apply the -al suffix to this word, as an adjective with the same meaning, or as an alternate form?

**Use Cases:**

- The wedding was an elysial event of grand stature and beautiful scenery
- The men were met by an elysial sight

I'm considering this form as part of the name of a business venture, and I am curious of the ramifications of using the word in this form.

Comment: I see a significant difference between *-ian* and *-ial* they not necessarily being interchangeable in all cases. In other words, *?elysian* is not (would not be) the same thing as *elysial.*

Comment: The word is "Elysian" - glance in a dictionary to find adjectives

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is either (1) inviting speculation about a non-word / 'word' not of 'accepted'  status and hence does not address English Language and Usage or (2) genref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, normally you **could** — except that because there already exists an adjective derived from *Elysium*,  *Elysian*, this blocks or at best interferes with creating an alternate adjective.

Trying to create *?Elysial* would be an uphill battle, since “We already have one, thank you very much”. Plus people will be constantly thinking you have misspelled the existing *Elysian*.

It is not always capitalized, particularly when used in an extended sense.  The OED gives this example of that:

> - 1882 Ouida *Maremma* I. 149 ― Vast grasslands··covered in spring with the elysian asphodel.

They also note that *elysian* has itself given rise to a further derived form via the *-ize* productive suffix:

> Hence **eˈlysianize** *v. intr*., to speak in terms of rapturous or extravagant approbation.
>
> - 1868 Bushnell *Serm. Living Subj*. 413 ― They··fall into a strain of elysianizing.

In my opinion, trying to have the existing *elysian* fight it out with your desired *?elysial* — and lose — would not be a battle worth waging.

Comment: Thanks! This is sensible and what I was starting to realize. Thank you for the effort.